# Semi group of operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I'm looking a book about evolutionary partial differential equations. More speceficly about semi-group of operator. 
I would like it contains a study for the transport equation and his infinitesimal generator.

Thanks you for your help !

Comment: The standard references, as far as I know, are Pazy, Goldstein, and Engel-Nagel.

Comment: Okay thank you, I could be great if there's a newer reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book **$\mathbf{C_0}$-Semigroups and Applications** by Ioan I. Vrabie is a good reference on the subject (in my opinion, as I explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2261138/70305)). The transpot equation is studied in [Section 4.4](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=T3lC9r51FEYC&pg=PA87&dq=%22More+precisely,+let+us+consider+the+transport+equation+along+the+direction%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjExJG9mpznAhVRDrkGHaUnDsQQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22More%20precisely%2C%20let%20us%20consider%20the%20transport%20equation%20along%20the%20direction%22&f=false).